# How to turn off php safe_mode off for a particular directory in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: php, linux, shared-hosting, cpanel

Hi I'm used shared hosting. I want to turn off php safe_mode off for my site. My provider gave me a php.ini file and asked me to put it with my settings in my public_html folder to override the settings, but it didn't work.

Comment: Posting the settings that you used would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to create a file called php.ini in the root (public_html or other) folder, and putting the following in it:

```
safe_mode = Off
```

Depending on server settings, this may or may not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your service provider might have forgot to tell you that you need to enable your user defined php.ini configuration by adding this line in the .htaccess file that you find in your public_html folder:

```
#Activates php.ini config located in main folder to work also recursively for all subfolders
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/YOUR_CPANEL_USER_NAME/public_html
```

Obviously replace YOUR_CPANEL_USER_NAME with your cPanel user name.

I'm supposing your server has got suPHP module(which is quite common in nowdays).

BTW: the php.ini file need to be in /home/YOUR_CPANEL_USER_NAME/public_html too and inside you should write this:

```
safe_mode = Off
```

And remember that Safe Mode is deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and is removed in PHP 6.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

You can turn it off by adding the following line to a .htaccess file in your root (public html) folder.

If the .htaccess file doesn't exist, you can create it using a simple text editing program.

```
php_flag safe_mode Off
```

Comment: This .htaccess could be added to a specific directory