# Setting safe mode to OFF in .htaccess file does not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, safe-mode, php-safe-mode

I'm on a server with safe mode on.
Now the server allows .htaccess files.
I have one in my public_html folder with settings of Wordpress.
Now in a sub-domain i want to insert an `.htaccess` file that dsiables safe mode.

i Tried theese:

```
php_value safe_mode 0
php_flag safe_mode 0
php_value safe_mode off
php_flag safe_mode off
```

but none worked.

Anyone knows how can i do that?
I Can not ask the server owner to disable safe mode, and basicly can't ask him anything.

Comment: The server owner can prevent safe mode from being turned off. That might be the reason why this doesn't work - or PHP isn't running as an Apache module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like he doesn't allow you to override safe mode. Which makes sense because what would be the point in running a shared server in safe mode if anyone could disable it as they saw fit. You're probably going to need to relocate to a server without safe mode as the only options for changing that value are not going to work for you. Safe mode is already deprecated and is not meant to be used. The "safe" way for a server owner to handle security is through the OS and setting up correct account permissions.

Comment: `safe mode` is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 5.4 (which is released just yesterday).

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to change the value of `safe_mode` in `.htaccess`. The configuration setting can only be set in `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`, as is [explained in the manpages](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php)

It also wouldn't be safe if it could be set in `.htaccess`. And it's removed in PHP 5.4, so that could be an argument to tell your hoster to disable it for you.

Comment: "you cannot disable functions on a per-virtualhost or per-directory basis in your httpd.conf file"

Comment: It's possible, just did it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to disable safe_mode by following instructions from Marco Demaio in last answer  in this question [How to turn off php safe_mode off for a particular directory in a shared hosting environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982197/how-to-turn-off-php-safe-mode-off-for-a-particular-directory-in-a-shared-hosting?rq=1)

I hope it works for you too!