# shell linux don't execute commande

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec

I have this command and it works fine on shell. 
I want to run it with php but it does not work
what i missed :

**edited :**

`$arg="arg1";` `$arg2= "arg2";`

```
echo shell_exec("sshpass -p ".escapeshellarg($arg)." ssh -t root@00.00.00.00 'asterisk -rx ".escapeshellarg($arg2)."'");
```

after this change no error on output but still commande not executed

**edited :**
the original commande is like this :

```
sshpass -p 'arg1' ssh -t root@00.00.00.00 'asterisk -rx "arg2"'
```

and i want to around the probleme with external parameters but it does not work

Comment: The problem that you're using single quote inside double qoutes to use functions. `echo shell_exec("sshpass -p ".escapeshellarg($arg)." ssh -t root@00.00.00.00 'asterisk -rx ".escapeshellarg($arg2)."'");` this will work.

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a good solution for who still search  :

I installed php-ssh2 with this link  (i use debian 8, php7)

[blog.programster.org](https://blog.programster.org/ubuntu-16-04-install-php-ssh2-extension)

and in my case i use codeigniter i follow the link to implement this class

[bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/joshdvir/codeigniter-ssh2-library/src/default/)

now i can execute any commande on shell without probleme

and the probleme is solved :)

Hope its help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

If the php is running on safe mode, it won't allow to execute `shell_exec` as it's described in the php manual:. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php

You can disabled the safe mode for a certain folder as it's described in the Stack Overflow question:

[How to turn off php safe_mode off for a particular directory in a shared hosting environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982197/how-to-turn-off-php-safe-mode-off-for-a-particular-directory-in-a-shared-hosting#1993234)

Comment: Can you edit the original post to replace the single quotes to double quotes as advised on the comment above and describe the output or which error do you receive.